# How do I handle real-time sensory data from a server in my Unity client?

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine, websocket, real-time-data

My prototype game consists of a UI panel with a text box. My requirement is to establish a connection with a server (possibly Node.js) and be able to change the text box content in my project in real time.

My idea is to create WebSockets and establish a TCP/IP connection to allow full duplex communication with the server. How do I change the text box content in my project from the data that is coming from the server?